# Is it possible to toggle a vim option when switching to insert mode?

Tags: spell-checking, vim

I recently discovered the spell option thanks to [this answer on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/810/review-the-vimrc-for-a-python-programmer/816#816), and I feel that the option is both really useful (while editing) and really annoying (while reading code, because of all the false positives).

I would like to somehow enable the option automatically when switching to insert mode:

```
set spell
```

and disable it automatically when switching back to normal mode:

```
set nospell
```

Comment: Good question... But I guess vim-related questions belong to superuser.com

Comment: @Denilson Sá: in the stackoverflow faq, it states "if your question generally covers... software tools commonly used by programmers ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!".  Therefore, vim-related questions belong on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @ Denilson Sá : Please see :  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25925/154445 As per the FAQ, Vim is considered a programmer tool and thus it is okay to keep it on SO.

Comment: @Denilson Sá: I was in doubt too, so I have checked the FAQ beforehand :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding the following commands in your `.vimrc` should do the trick (as long as your not using CTRL+C to leave insert mode) :

```
autocmd InsertEnter * setlocal spell
autocmd InsertLeave * setlocal nospell
```

Since this is a great trick, I have added these lines to my `.vimrc` !

if you want to get rid of words being highlighted, you can add them to the "good" word list by putting the cursor over them and type `zg`. See `:help spell`for more information

Comment: I use commands like this to change colorscheme so it's very obvious whether I'm in insert mode or not.

Comment: Nice one! Personally, I'd switch these around, so that spell checking was only enabled in normal mode. I prefer not to be bothered by SpellBad highlighting while I compose, and I can fix the typos faster when I'm in normal mode (using `[s` and `]s` to jump between typos). Anyway, each to their own.

Comment: Wow, I learned a lot about the spell check in Vim. Off to read up :help spell. Thanks @Xavier and @nelstrom

Comment: @Amjith I made [a screencast about using Vim's spell checker](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/spell-checking/), which might give you some more ideas.